# How to add elements/objects faster into a list?

Tags: c#, .net, list

Lets say I have something like this:

```
MySomething element1 = new MySomething(stuff);
MySomething element2 = new MySomething(stuff);
MySomething element3 = new MySomething(stuff);
MySomething element4 = new MySomething(stuff);
MySomething element5 = new MySomething(stuff);
//and so on...
```

Now lets say I have a list or something somewhere and I would like to add all of the elements to the list. They I have to to do:

```
myList.add(element1);
myList.add(element2);
//and so on...
```

That would take long. And If I would have 100+ elements, well it takes forever ^^ Is there a faster way to add that much of created 'elements' into a list? I know

```
myList.add(new MySomething(stuff));
```

But let say, the elements were already created like here in example. How to add them in c# into a list faster? Thank you :)

Edit: ok and I have to say, the names are not always element1-100 its sometime element23, element454 and so on. The number after element is not always sequential. And yes they are all of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are all of the same type and you know how many you need just use a loop to create an array initially:

```
MySomething[] items = new MySomething[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    items[i] = new MySomething(stuff);
}
```

later, add all items to the list:

```
list.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: Instead of looping on the second step, you could use the List.AddRange(T[] array) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddRange(<T>)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx

but I'm pretty sure the internal implementation just iterates through the collection and adds every element one by one

Answer (score 0):

If you know ahead of time how many elements you'll be adding into the list, you can set the size of the list in the constructor - this saves the list from being resized dynamically as it then fills up e.g.

```
MySomething element1 = new MySomething(stuff);
....
MySomething element100 = new Something(stuff);

List<MySomething> myList = new List<MySomething>(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a method that yields return every object that you create inside:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
var list = Enumerable
  .Range(1,100)
  .Select(i =>  new MySomething(stuff))
  .ToList();
```